# Why is the variable in Querydsl5.0 null?

Tags: spring-boot, querydsl

I'm trying to experiment with Querydsl 5.0 in Springboot3.0. but, QEntity variable is null.
The descriptor is as follows:

```java
public class BiddingAnnouncementEntity extends BaseDateEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idx;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_idx", nullable = false)
    private AccountEntity account;

    @Column(length = 500, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(length = 5000, nullable = false)
    private String content;
}
```

```java
public class BiddingAnnouncementCommentEntity extends BaseDateEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private BiddingAnnouncementCommentKey commentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_idx", nullable = false)
    private AccountEntity account;

    @Column(length = 5000, nullable = false)
    private String content;
}
```

Primary key class for BiddingAnnouncementCommentEntity

```java
public class BiddingAnnouncementCommentKey implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "announcement_idx", nullable = false)
    private BiddingAnnouncementEntity biddingAnnouncement;

    @Column(name = "sequence_no")
    private Long sequenceNo;
}
```

```java
public class BiddingAnnouncementCommentRecommendEntity extends BaseDateEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private BiddingAnnouncementCommentRecommendKey recommendId;
}
```

Primary key class for BiddingAnnouncementCommentRecommendEntity

```java
public class BiddingAnnouncementCommentRecommendKey implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "announcement_idx", nullable = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sequence_no", nullable = false)
    private BiddingAnnouncementCommentEntity biddingAnnouncementComment;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_idx", nullable = false)
    private AccountEntity account;
}
```

I want to search by `QBiddingAnnouncementCommentRecommend Class`.

**My query is**

```java
    private final JPAQueryFactory query;

    QBiddingAnnouncementCommentRecommendEntity announcementCommentRecommend = new QBiddingAnnouncementCommentRecommendEntity("announcementCommentRecommend");


public void getBiddingAnnouncementCommentRecommendList(long userIdx, long announcementIdx) {
    query.selectFrom(announcementCommentRecommend)
    .where(announcementCommentRecommend.recommendId.biddingAnnouncementComment.commentId.biddingAnnouncement.idx.eq(announcementIdx))
    .fetch()
}
```

**Output**

```
Cannot read field "biddingAnnouncement" because "this.announcementCommentRecommend.recommendId.biddingAnnouncementComment.commentId" is null
```

How do I fix this?